# Apache rewrite mod breaking apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, drupal

I am setting up Drupal Open Atrium, and halfway through the configuration receive an error:

> Clean Urls must be available and enabled to use OpenAtrium.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/enable-clean-urls tells me to run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, which happens:

```
Enabling module rewrite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
service apache2 restart
```

but when I then run `sudo service apache2 restart` I get the following error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status apache2.service` returns:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-04-03 18:21:04 UTC; 7s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 11268 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 11345 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 apache2[11345]:  *
Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 apache2[11345]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 apache2[11345]: Output of config test was:
Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 apache2[11345]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rew
Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 apache2[11345]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 apache2[11345]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 03 18:21:04 ip-172-31-31-251 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The problem sorts itself out with a `a2dismod rewrite`, but then I'm back where I started.

My `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load` looks like this, if that's the trouble.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

How can I get the rewrite mod to work with apache?

Answer (score 2):

This was finally solved by using `sudo apache2ctl graceful` and following the file links from the error messages, for example:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load: LoadModule takes two arguments, a module name and the name of a shared object file to load it from
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

In the end, I removed the `AddModule mod_rewrite.c` from the `rewrite.load` that was suggested by [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/15365), and changed the link from `modules/mod_rewrite.so` to `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so` which is where it actually was (found with `sudo find / -name mod_rewrite.so`)

I then restarted apache, and everything worked!

Comment: Thanks for this, why don't you update the drupal page?